# Format color while typing in textarea or pre

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, pre

I'm trying to create a comments section that lets users @someone. When the user types @random and then space, I want it to be highlighted. So I've created something that searches and replaces the string, but I then when the html is replaced, it places the cursor at the beginning. Any way to solve this? Any other way of doing something like this?

```js
$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
  txt = this.innerText.split(" ")
  new_txt = this.innerText
  for (var i = txt.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (txt[i].startsWith('@') == false) {
      delete txt[i]
    }
  }
  txt = txt.sort().join(" ").trim().split(" ")
  console.log(txt)
  if (txt.length > 0 && txt[0] != "") {
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
      new_txt = new_txt.replace(txt[i], '<mark>' + txt[i] + '</mark>')
    }
    $('#my_console_log').text(new_txt)
    this.innerHTML = new_txt
  }
});
```

```css
pre {
  border: solid black 1px;
}

mark {
  background: blue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<title>Test page</title>
<form>
  <pre id='textarea' contentEditable='true'></pre>
  <div id="my_console_log"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple [plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Facebook-Like-Hashtag-Highlighting-Plugin-with-jQuery-hashtags-js/) available which can be useful to you, 
Download the plugin and edit the file **jquery.hashtags.js** and remove the condition for **#**. You can also change the style as per your requirement.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.hashtags = function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="jqueryHashtags"><div class="highlighter"></div></div>').unwrap().before('<div class="highlighter"></div>').wrap('<div class="typehead"></div></div>');
    $(this).addClass("theSelector");
    autosize($(this));
    $(this).on("keyup", function() {
        var str = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").css("width",$(this).css("width"));
        str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
        if(!str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g) && !str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g) && !str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?#([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g) && !str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?@([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g)) {

            // Remove below condition for hashtag.
            if(!str.match(/#(([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+)|([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ가-힣]+)|([ぁ-んァ-ン]+)|([一-龯]+))#/g)) { //arabic support, CJK support
                str = str.replace(/#(([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+)|([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ가-힣]+)|([ぁ-んァ-ン]+)|([一-龯]+))/g,'<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
            }else{
                str = str.replace(/#(([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+)|([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ가-힣]+)|([ぁ-んァ-ン]+)|([一-龯]+))#(([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+)|([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ가-힣]+)|([ぁ-んァ-ン]+)|([一-龯]+))/g,'<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
            }

            // Keep this condition.
            if(!str.match(/@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+)|([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ가-힣]+)|([ぁ-んァ-ン]+)|([一-龯]+))@/g)) {
                str = str.replace(/@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+)|([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ가-힣]+)|([ぁ-んァ-ン]+)|([一-龯]+))/g,'<span class="hashtag">@$1</span>');
            }else{
                str = str.replace(/@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+)|([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ가-힣]+)|([ぁ-んァ-ン]+)|([一-龯]+))@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+)|([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ가-힣]+)|([ぁ-んァ-ン]+)|([一-龯]+))/g,'<span class="hashtag">@$1</span>');
            }
        }
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").html(str);
    });
    $(this).parent().prev().on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".theSelector").focus();
    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the html just append a class with the color that you want